# Is this right to convert bytes to GB?

Tags: java

I want to check how much memory is used in my Java application, and I then used:

```
 System.out.println("Free memory (bytes): " +
                    Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/(1024*1024*1024));
```

I converted the byte amounts to GB. But on Google, it shows that a byte= 1e-9 gb. which one is right?

Comment: Depends. It can be (1000 * 1000 * 1000) **or** (1024 * 1024 * 1024). Depends on who's selling it, and the type of memory.

Comment: btw `b` = bit, `B` = byte. `g` = grams, `G` = giga.

Answer (score 3):

The JVM always uses [gibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) or 1024^3 or `1 << 30` which should be written as GiB for clarity but isn't always done consistently.

I suggest you choose GB = 1000^3 or GiB = 1024^3 and write the unit with the result to make it clear which you mean.  I would also show some digits of precision e.g.

```
System.out.println("Free memory: " +
                   (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() * 1000 >> 30) / 1e3 + 
                   " GiB"));
```

or

```
System.out.println("Free memory: " +
                   (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1_000_000 / 1e3 + 
                   " GB"));
```

In both cases, it will show 3 digits of precision.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the perspective.

Technically, 1 gigabyte is 1024 megabytes.

But from storage's view, it is calculated as 1000 megabytes.

So it doesn't matter that much and you can choose which perspective you are going to tell with.